# Apache OpenNLP POSModel delay when initialized in Android

Tags: android, opennlp

I'm creating an app on Android which uses a part of speech tagger from Apache (OpenNLP). The app works okay, but for some reason there is large delay when it creates the part of speech tagger from a database file (en-pos-maxent.bin). I'm using Android Studio, and the database is in app/res/raw/en-pos-maxent.bin. Here's the code that initializes the POSModel:

```
public POSModel setupPOSTagger() {
        InputStream modelIn = null;
        POSModel model = null;
        try {
            modelIn = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.en_pos_maxent);
  //the huge delay is mainly on the line below
            model = new POSModel(modelIn);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Model loading failed, handle the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (modelIn != null) {
                try {
                    modelIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Any ideas?